# JNI access violation without calling any function

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm currently writing some Java application and I have to use some native libraries (C++) that I also wrote. JNI is generated by SWIG.
Most of the time it works perfectly good but from time to time I'm getting an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error and everithing crashes. Strangly, when this is happening I'm not calling any native function.

In error log I've found

"Problematic frame:
 C  [profiler.dll+0x4e0e4]  Java_testpackage_testJNI_interface_1compute+0x375b8"

but I'm not using this compute() function at all. It is the last function in testJNI.java and interface.java files generated by SWIG. When I've removed this function from code (both in java and c++) I'm still getting same error but with another function - also the last one.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Which arrays are pinned and when are they released? Are you working on bytebuffers?

Comment: Nope, native functions are only returning primitives (and Strings). Sometimes i'm also calling natives with Strings argument. This could be a problem?